# API Call Not Returning Information

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios

I am trying to call [this API](https://rapidapi.com/systran/api/systran-io-translation-and-nlp) using axios in React. I have used this method previously whereby the request is wrapped in a function and exported to the main app component, but I'm just not getting the required result.

```js
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  method: "GET",
  url:
    "https://systran-systran-platform-for-language-processing-v1.p.rapidapi.com/resources/dictionary/lookup",
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
    "x-rapidapi-host":
      "systran-systran-platform-for-language-processing-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": process.env.apiKey
  },
  params: {
    source: "de",
    target: "en"
  }
});
```

I really want to just use the imported axios request like so:

```js
  const addCurrentWord = async () => {
    const response = await systran.get("", { params: { input: "wunderbar" } });
    console.log(response.data.outputs[0].output.matches[0].targets[0].lemma);
    setDefinition(response.data.outputs[0].output.matches[0].targets[0].lemma);
    setWordId(prevId => prevId + 1);
    setCurrentWords(prevWords => [
      ...prevWords,
      { id: wordId, word: enteredWord, definition: definition }
    ]);
  };
```

Despite having done it in this way several times before, I just don't know what is going wrong this time. The error I get in this case seems to do with the json object not being available by the time it is referenced, but I thought that async await would mean that nothing would happen until the json object was ready to be used.

The weird thing is that when I try using the code snipped from RapidAPI directly inside the App component like so:

```js
const axios = require("axios");

axios({
    "method":"GET",
    "url":"https://systran-systran-platform-for-language-processing-v1.p.rapidapi.com/translation/text/translate",
    "headers":{
    "content-type":"application/octet-stream",
    "x-rapidapi-host":"systran-systran-platform-for-language-processing-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key":"4f86f3edfdmshf18247783d4906cp1eef26jsn606d81d0aed8"
    },"params":{
    "source":"{
    source
    }",
    "target":"{
    target
    }",
    "input":"{
    input
    }"
    }
    })
    .then((response)=>{
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error)
    })
```

I am able to get the correct information from the API request. I can console.log `response.data.outputs[0].output.matches[0].targets[0].lemma` without an issue.
But this has the major drawback of making my App component huge and cumbersome. I really don't want this chunk of code clogging up my App component. I just can't understand how this is any different from the other method of exporting the API call from another component.

REST APIs always give me major headaches as there is a lot I do not understand, I would love to learn something that could help me here!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies with the bug described in issue [Request params are not getting merged with instance params](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2190)

You also do not need to pass the empty string for the url. Just pass the options.

So i think using

```js
const response = await systran.get({
  params: {
    source: 'de',
    target: 'en',
    input: "wunderbar"
  }
});
```

should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip, but unfortunately this is not the issue. This code still returns an error:


const addCurrentWord = async () => {
    const response = await systran.get("", { params: { input: "wunderbar", source: "de",
    target: "en" } });
    console.log(response.data.outputs[0].output.matches[0].targets[0].lemma);
    setDefinition(response.data.outputs[0].output.matches[0].targets[0].lemma);
    setWordId(prevId => prevId + 1);
    setCurrentWords(prevWords => [
      ...prevWords,
      { id: wordId, word: enteredWord, definition: definition }
    ]);
  };

Comment: The error says "Cannot read property "0" of undefined", meaning that the json object has not been defined by the time it is called

Comment: @erasebegin first try without the empty string so change `systran.get("", {` to `systran.get({`. Then open the devtools and go to network tab and see if the request to the endpoint you want was made as expected and what the results were